# MYSQL - Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to SQL. I get an error executing the following trigger . Please Help

```
delimiter $$
create trigger cheque_update_trigger 
after insert on cheque_details 
for each row  begin  
declare banktype text; declare branchrefno int ; 
select branch_ref_no into branchrefno from customer_account where acct_no = New.acct_no; 
select type into banktype from branch_table where branch_ref_no = branchrefno; 
if (type = 'ab') then  
insert into ab_cheque_register values ( New.cheque_no, branchrefno, New.fbank_ref_no, New.amount);
else if (type = 'nab') then  
insert into nab_cheque_register values( New.cheque_no,  branchrefno);  
insert into osb_cheque_register values( New.cheque_no, branchrefno); else  
insert into osb_cheque_register values(New.cheque_no, branchrefno);> end if;  
end if;
end$$
delimiter;
```

Comment: If you share the error it'd be easier to help...

Comment: Please update question with more details. Other wise it will flagged as low quality

Comment: **"I get an error"** is not a sufficient description of the problem. A MySQL error message includes *details* that describe the actual problem, not just some nebulous "there's an error". Did you have a *question* you wanted to ask?

Comment: Hey all...sorry i wanted someone to check out what the problem was as i got error after every single line..it's tedious to put all the error statements. Next time ill make sure i give proper details :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a spurious greater than symbol character (**`>`**) on the line with the last insert. Likely that will be causing an error.

Also, on that last line, put a space between **`DELIMITER`** and the semicolon. (My personal preference is to have the `DELIMITER`  statement preceded and followed by a blank line.)

---

NOTE: Usually, when MySQL throws a syntax error, the error message usually includes an indication of where MySQL thinks the problem is. That that can help us narrow down where the actual problem is; but we need the actual error message.

---

There's also a reference to an undeclared variable **`type`** in the IF statements, that will also cause an error.

The names of the variables appear to be the same as column names. That's allowed, but when there's a collision (when a reference could be to either), important to note that in MySQL, precedence is given to the variable name. We typically avoid this by 1) qualifying column references with the table alias, and 2) naming the variables in a way that does not cause collisions.

Based on the OP trigger definition, I'd recommend something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER cheque_update_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON cheque_details 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
   DECLARE v_banktype    TEXT;
   DECLARE v_branchrefno INT; 

   SELECT a.branch_ref_no
     INTO v_branchrefno 
     FROM customer_account a
    WHERE a.acct_no = NEW.acct_no
    LIMIT 1;

   SELECT b.type 
     INTO v_banktype
     FROM branch_table b
    WHERE b.branch_ref_no = v_branchrefno
    LIMIT 1;

   IF ( v_banktype = 'ab' ) THEN
     INSERT INTO ab_cheque_register (cheque_no, branch_ref_no, fbank_ref_no, amount) 
     VALUES ( NEW.cheque_no, v_branchrefno, NEW.fbank_ref_no, NEW.amount);
   ELSE
     IF ( v_banktype = 'nab' ) THEN
       INSERT INTO nab_cheque_register (cheque_no, branch_ref_no) 
       VALUES ( NEW.cheque_no, v_branchrefno);
     END IF;
     INSERT INTO osb_cheque_register (cheque_no, branch_ref_no) 
     VALUES ( NEW.cheque_no, v_branchrefno);
   END IF;  
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This style of formatting makes it *MUCH* easier on the poor soul that has to read and decipher the trigger definition.

(Is "`banktype`" actually defined as `TEXT` datatype? Seems much more likely this column would be defined as VARCHAR, CHAR or ENUM.)

Comment: Thanks a tonne :) That helped. Sorry abt tht > before else, it was my mistake while trying to convert the code as blockquote..new to stackoverflow as well !! And yea the formatting...quite a novice :D Thanks :)